# When using the ExactTarget API I get an error

Tags: error

```
 { Results:
      [ { StatusCode: 'Error',
          StatusMessage: 'No member context has been set on the thread.',
          OrdinalID: 0,
          ErrorCode: 4002,
          NewID: ,
          Object:
           { attributes: { 'xsi:type': 'Email' },
             Name: '[00454571] Interruption Start [1]',
             CategoryID: '1250228',
```

This error comes up when trying to send through the API, what could be the cause? the issue just started recently.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using the old wsdl/endpoints at:

https://etappx.exacttarget.com/etframeworksf.wsdl

Try pointing your service to the new endpoints at:

https://webservice.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl

That fixed it for me, anyway.